# elasticsearch jdbc river polling--- load data from mysql repeatedly

Tags: plugins, jdbc, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

When using https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc I notice that the following curl statement successfully indexes data the first time. However, the river fails to repeatedly poll the database for updates.

To restate, when I run the following, the river successfully connects to MySQL, runs the query successfully, indexes the results, but never runs the query again.

```
curl -XPUT '127.0.0.1:9200/_river/projects_river/_meta' -d '{
"type" : "jdbc",
"index" : {
    "index" : "test_projects",
    "type" : "project",
    "bulk_size" : 100,
    "max_bulk_requests" : 1,
    "autocommit": true
    },
"jdbc" : {
    "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "poll" : "1m",
    "strategy" : "simple",
    "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
    "user" : "root",
    "sql" : "SELECT name, updated_at from projects p where p.updated_at > date_sub(now(),interval 1 minute)"
    }
}'
```

Tailing the log, I see:

> [2013-09-27 16:32:24,482][INFO ][org.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverFlow] next run, waiting 1m
>   [2013-09-27 16:33:24,488][INFO ]> [org.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverFlow] next run, waiting 1m
>   [2013-09-27 16:34:24,494][INFO ]> [org.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverFlow] next run, waiting 1m

But the index stays empty. Running on a macbook pro with elasticsearch version stable 0.90.2, HEAD and mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar in the river pligns directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you switch your strategy value from "simple" to "poll" you may get what you are looking for - it has worked for me with jdbc on that version of elasticsearch against MS SQL.

Also - you will need to select a field as _id (select primarykey as _id) as this is used in the elasticsearch river for determining what records are added/deleted/updated.

Comment: Accepting your answer even though i didnt try it--  passing digesting false and autocommit true worked for me.